# homomorphisms induce isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume that we have the following commutative diagram with groups and homomorphisms 
where  $b$ and $c$ are injective homomorphisms

$\begin{array}[c]{ccc}
A&\stackrel{a}{\rightarrow}&B\\
\downarrow\scriptstyle{b}&&\downarrow\scriptstyle{c}\\
C&\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}&D
\end{array}$

Is it true that $C/b(A) \cong D/c(B)$? Why?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $A$ and $B$ both be trivial groups. What does your question ask in this case?

Comment: are they some conditions on the groups and the homomorphisms to have correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. 
Put 
$A = B = C = G$ and $D = G \times G$. 
$a$ , $b$ identity , $c$ $d$ inclusion on the first factor.

Then
$C/b(A) = \{e\}$ and $D/c(B) \simeq G$

Comment: are they some conditions on the groups and the homomorphisms to have correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's not true, take $A=B=C=0$ (the trivial group) and $D$ any nontrivial group.

It is however true that $d$ induces an isomorphism $C/b(A) \to d(C)$. For this isomorphism to be an isomorphism $C/b(A) \simeq D/c(B)$, you would need $B$ to be trivial (since $c$ is injective) and $d$ to be surjective. Injectivity of $b$ doesn't matter.

Comment: are they some conditions on the groups and the homomorphisms to have correct answer?

Comment: @Danial: I edited my answer to give a possible condition.